# Perl update - should I reinstall modules?

Tags: perl, module, installation

Should I reinstall the modules when updating from Perl `5.14` to `5.14.1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Perl will add the 5.14.0 INC path to the 5.14.1 INC path so you shouldn't have to reinstall any modules as Perl maintains binary compatibility between minor versions.  Any new modules you install will just be visible to 5.14.1, though.

You might want to use something like App::perlbrew if you do want to keep your installations segregated.

Comment: Nit: Partial binary compatibility. Binaries are compatible with newer Perls of the same version, but not necessarily the other way around. e.g. A module built with 5.14.0 is suppose to work with Perl 5.14.1, but a module built with 5.14.1 may not work with Perl 5.14.0.